# Google or Unity analytics wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-analytics

**Can anyone please help on this issues?**

We use several different resources to collect analytics data from the application:
a) one of them show us 1000 new users per day
b) Unity Analytics show us only 400 per day, sometimes much less, but not more
c) Google play show us 1000 installations per day

**1.Why is unity Analytics showing only a part of users and not all of them?
 
2.Has anyone had anything like this?**

**PS** 
1. events are configured correctly and if it was in them, then there would be no users.
2. we know that unity analytics can process data for up to 24 hours, so they may not be displayed immediately. But in the end, the data do not converge in any way.

Comment: It could be that 600 user only installed the app, but never started it.

Comment: In the begining we think about it.  But other analytics show us 1000 events of uniq start game, like "first_session_start".  
It's good idea, but we cheked it. 
Thank you!

Comment: Which other analytic tools do you use?

Comment: analytic tools - Infinario